# What happens if SharePoint timer service stops?

Tags: sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, service

Please let me know what happens when share point timer stops? Can web application work?

Comment: Yes web applications will work even if the Timer Service is stopped.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, The web application will work fine. because it relies on IIS!

> The SharePoint Timer service is a windows service that runs other
>   services according to schedules specified in timer jobs.  If it stops,
>   all services and timer jobs controlled by the SharePoint timer service
>   will be stopped, use Get-SPTimerJob to return timer jobs

**Additional references**

- [Get-SPTimerJob](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-sptimerjob?view=sharepoint-ps)
- [SharePoint Timer service](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2011/10/26/the-sharepoint-timer-service/)

Answer (score 6):

**1. What happens when share point timer stops?**

As Chicago has mentioned, If it stops, all services and timer jobs controlled by the SharePoint timer service will be stopped. This means:

1. Your workflows will stop
2. Alert mails will stop
3. Search crawling will stop  (means you will not able to search new items)
4. Cleanup Jobs will stop (this will result in increase of SharePoint_Config db, which will eat disk space of db server)
5. Audit and Analytics will stop
6. and etc. etc.

**2. Can web application works?**

Yes. with above issues.

Comment: my question would be, how to restart the SP Timer Job and at same time will all the above mention points start working from that instance ?! or will they have to be re-run ?

Comment: You can start the timer service from services or using powershell. All the above mention points start working from that instance.

Answer (score 3):

Basically it depends, SharePoint web Application depend upon IIS, database and timer services. If IIS or database not available then it will down completely but if SharePoint time service stopped then web Application will work partially.

- You May Get Unexpected Error On pages of site collection.
- Alerts Will Not Work
- Workflow will not work
- Syncing Of Database With Profile Stopped.
- Any custom timer job will not work and much more.
- Information Rights Policy will not work
- there are many components inside the web application which relies on this service.

Now,Recycling the timer service is not a big issue as it will cause the minor outage for a couple of seconds, During the Restart process, all the running jobs will go into paused state and jobs which are scheduled during that time frame will not run But will catch on next schedule once the Timer Service is back.

Another thing, there is Scheduled timer job in Sharepoint which automatically recycle the Timer Service every day 6 am( default scheduled). Read this blog to understand more about it.https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2012/01/10/the-timer-recycle-job-job-timer-recycle/

Note: dont kill the timer service from the Task manager always use the script